# How to get all selected rows if only parts of rows are selected?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

How to select all rows in which something is seleccted? Say we have selected 10 items in all in difrent/same columns, in multiple rows like this:

[image]

And we want to get result similar to

```
var selected = ElementsTableView.SelectedRows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>();
```

yet for all rows in which is selected at least one column item. How to do such thing with WinForms in C#?

Comment: So you want to create an array of rows, made up of every row that has at least one value selected in it?

Comment: @ChrisCooney: Yes I do!)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

```
var selected = ElementsTableView
               .SelectedCells
               .Cast<DataGridViewCell>()
               .Select(c => c.OwningRow)
               .Distinct();
```

Comment: +1. Wow, I did not expect that to be possible, as easy as this.

Answer (score 1):

The `DataGridView` has a `SelectedCells` property.   `DataGridViewCell` has an `OwningRow` property which returns the `DataGridViewRow`.

See the MSDN documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectedcells.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.owningrow.aspx).